What's wrong with Lithium BCC(100) slab and implicit solvation?
A colleague is having a rough time getting his Lithium slab BCC(100) to converge when using QuantumEspresso + Environ, so I decided to give it a shot but I can't make it converge neither. SCF seems to be oscillating as soon as the polarization charge kicks in, changing environ_thr does not have any impact... I tried a bunch of stuff:

Changing the pseudopotential
Increasing the number of bands + smearing
Playing with general convergence parameters (mixing...)
It seems that when env_static_permittivity > 2 there is no way to make this slab converge.

Having a look at the structure it seems that it is quite complex in the sense that there are quite big holes (pictures attached) which I though might requires solvent aware options?
At the same time a Pt(111) slab is extremely easy to converge, can someone explain what is the problem here?


This seems like an ab initio confirmation that lithium metal is pretty reactive and easily oxidised in polar protic solvents ...

@ShernRenTee Thanks for the comment, yes I've heard of that (I am not lithium expert) but with implicit solvation? Really? I would expect to have a world between polar protic solvents and continuum models?

Solvent permittivity reduces the energy of electric field inhomogeneity in-solution. IRL this is how solvents stabilise ions. In silico, reducing the solvent-region energy makes more-inhomogeneous electron distributions more accessible, increasing charge sloshing, compounded by Li having minimal inner electronic shielding of valence electrons from nuclear charges, resulting in robust electronic vibrations that are difficult to damp down and minimise.

... which I am writing as a comment because I write it purely from physical intuition and some formal knowledge of the density functional math representations. I have never done any useful production DFT simulations and I leave it to those who have to tell me if I am completely off-target.
